# Setting up two separate APs to 1 router within the same subnetwork

Tags: networking, router, home-networking, dhcp, wireless-access-point

My home network situation is as following (simplified):

[image: Overview]

I have one main router (with DHCP on) and want to have two routers in AP mode (with DHCP turned off, connected via LAN ports) within the same subnetwork. I thought that such DHCP setup would make it work, however I am experiencing some problems. Some new devices are straight up refusing to have proper IPs assigned to them, when I run the setup with just one AP working at the time all seems to be fine. Is that kind of setup wrong? If so, what would be a better alternative?

Comment: Did you make sure there are no IP address conflicts between the three routers?

Comment: Each router has separate IP outside of main router's DHCP range (192.168.55.1, 192.168.55.2 and 192.168.55.3) while DHCP range on main router is set up as 192.168.55.100 - 192.168.55.252. Subnet mask is /24.

Comment: Sounds like what you have done is correct. Maybe flash the router with dd-wrt or get a better quality router. It sounds like the router is problematic. Also, are your APs running the same SSID as the router? This should be correct, but maybe the router is treating the man and WiFi interfaces differently to provide "WiFi isolation" or some such?

Comment: All SSIDs are exactly the same, my main router has WiFi off while APs have WiFi on.